# Is it possible to make a custom sorting (not ascending or descending) with help of engine?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a data to be sorted, but it should be a custom sorting defined by mine rules.

For example I need to print values in this order:

```
B 
C
A
D
```

It is not an ascending or descending sorting.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment you can use `sortField`

Comment: ok done! got it. Put the field to sort as a Variable.added condition.then added it in the sort field. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is possible to make sorting via *JasperReports engine* (without help of query language, for example SQL).

This can be done with help of ***sortField*** attribute of main dataset or ***subDataset***.

#### The sample of report without sorting

The *jrxml* for report without sorting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Non sorted data" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ds">
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <summary>
        <band height="15">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ds">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("def", "jkl", "abc", "ghi"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="15" width="311">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The result in *Jaspersoft Studio (JSS)*  will be:

[image: Non sorted data]

After adding sorting with help of ***sortField*** the template will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sorted data" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ds">
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <sortField name="value"/>
    </subDataset>
    <summary>
        <band height="15">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ds">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("def", "jkl", "abc", "ghi"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="15" width="311">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

and the result in *JSS*:

[image: The sorted data]

The custom sorting can be implemented in several ways

#### 1. Using sortField attribute

The ***sortField*** attribute may deal not only with fields, but also with variables.
If it possible, we can move the sorting logic here (to variable).

The simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Data with custom sorting" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ds">
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <sortField name="valueForSorting" type="Variable"/>
        <variable name="valueForSorting" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA["a".equalsIgnoreCase($F{value}) ? 3 :  "b".equalsIgnoreCase($F{value}) ? 1 : "c".equalsIgnoreCase($F{value}) ? 2 : "d".equalsIgnoreCase($F{value}) ? 4 : 0]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
    </subDataset>
    <summary>
        <band height="15">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ds">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("d", "c", "b", "a"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="15" width="311">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The result in *JSS*  will be:

[image: The custom sorted data]

#### 2. Using query tricks

In some cases using *CASE* operator can help us to sort data like we want.

For example:

```
SELECT value,
  CASE
    WHEN value = 'a' THEN 3
    WHEN value = 'b' THEN 1
    WHEN value = 'c' THEN 2
    WHEN value = 'd' THEN 4
    ELSE 0
    END AS valueForSorting
FROM someTable
```

#### 3. Custom datasources

The using custom datasource is another way to sort data. We can sort data in *Java* code and then pass datasource to the report.

#### 4. Using crosstab

The crosstab component is using mechanism of sorting data - we can set the custom behaviour for sorting.